# Fix the "Invalid Address" error, after upgrading to Joomla 3.5.1

Tags: joomla-3.x, upgrade, joomla-mail

After upgrading to Joomla 3.5.1, I get an `Invalid Address` error in some of my extensions that use PHPMailer (the Joomla Mailing system).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Answer for Users:

If you are getting this error because you are using some extension that sends emails, please visit the developer page, and first **make sure you are using the latest version**.

If you are 100% sure that you are using the latest version, but still getting this error, you should contact the developer and ask them about this error. **Sending them a link to this page, may help the developer to fix this error**.

If you consider yourself experienced enough with PHP, you may try to patch the code on your own, using the "answer for developers", below.

Please note that this will not be a permanent solution, but just a "patch", until the developer issues a new version.

### Answer for Developers:

Joomla 3.5.1 enables PHPMailer's exceptions by default. Thus errors that were previously hidden show up.

One case where this shows now is with the `addReplyTo` function.

In Joomla 2.5 `addReplyTo` had an array parameter.

Beginning with Joomla 3.0 ([yes, back in 2012](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/c7c3722157456f1ea29732b51728006a2ae509a8/libraries/joomla/mail/mail.php)) Joomla's JMail function changed to not handle arrays differently than string parameters. Thus it relied on the underlying PHPMailer code, which however changed also and thus fails to add the Reply-To correctly.

PHPMailer does throw an Exception for that, however up until Joomla 3.5.1 nobody saw that exception if you did not enable the exception handling manually!

**Solution**

You may search your extension code for `addReplyTo` and change lines like this:

```
 $mailer->addReplyTo(array($replyTo, $replyToName));
```

to this:

```
if(version_compare(JVERSION, '3.0', 'ge')) {
  $mailer->addReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName);
} else {
  $mailer->addReplyTo(array($replyTo, $replyToName));
}
```

Furthermore you want to add `try {} catch() {}` code as needed to handle the Exception coming from JMail/PHPMailer.

More information:

[Discussion of the issue on Github](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/9577)

[Relevant topic in Joomla forums](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=708&p=3386464)

Comment: Nice find. I wish Joomla provided pages like [this](https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2) for their updates

Comment: As per the edit made by hbit, this is an issue since Joomla 3.0. However, I can confirm, that up to Joomla 3.5, this problem does not occur with any form using the old code.

Answer (score 3):

I also got this error when the $replyTo variable was empty and had to use

```
if ( !empty($replyTo) ) {
  $mailer->addReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName);
}
```